# javascript jquery call action before modal dialog show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link like:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-dialog" class="my_table" >
```

And I want to bind jquery action that will work before modal dialog show.

```
$(document).on('click','.my_table',function(){
   alert('Execute before!');
})
```

But modal dialog still visible. First I get alerted, then modal dialog. How to make dialog wait until the alert is `closed/callback` processed? Please don't suggest to open dialog by JQuery, it doesn't work in current CSS/HTML mockup.

Answer (score 1):

Create javascript function and call it on your element click.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" onclick="callFunc();" class="my_table"></a>
<script>
   function callFunc() {
      alert('Execute before!');
      $('#modal-dialog').appendTo('body').modal('show');
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must handle modal show event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      alert('Execute before!');
  })
});
```